# Why does a 'docker push' to repository leads to multiple pushes of images

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu-14.04, dockerhub

I have a docker image - `sudheeshms1/node_ubuntu` with the virtual size of around **795.9 MB**. When I try to push it to the docker hub/public repository, I could see a bunch of other images(not present in my local machine) that is being pushed one after the other, each with an average size of **70-400 MB** and thus crossing my bandwidth limit. Could some one please tell me why other images are being pushed in addition to the intended one?

```
Docker version: 1.0.1, build 990021a

Ubuntu: 14.04
```

Please refer below image for clarity.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to docker [architecture](https://docs.docker.com/introduction/understanding-docker/), an image consists of layers, which could be combined by docker with help of union file systems. Everytime an image changes, creates a new layer. When you push an image into a repository, docker pushes not a whole image, but all it new layers.

In your case, it's not a multiple pushes of images, but just pushes of all layers, that are new for those remote repo.

Comment: hey @stanislav so can't one stop that coz it pushes alot of images that means huge MB's of data which is not even needed? Can't i push the changes?... for example (far distant example) git?